# How do I create an object from two array indexes?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a javascript object with two array indexes, but it does not seem possible. Why is that? For example:

```
var arr = ["name","john"];
var obj = {arr[0]:arr[1]}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Computed property names need brackets `[myPropName]`

```js
var arr = ["name","john"]
var obj = {[arr[0]]:arr[1]}

obj.name // 'john'
```

Comment: Good answer. I forgot about the brackets with my answer. Deleted it since this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `arr[0]` then js will understand that the property name is `arr[0]` not "name", so you need `[arr[0]]` for it to interpret as "name"
`var obj = {[arr[0]]:arr[1]}`

Answer (score 0):

You can also do `Object.assign`,

```js
var arr = ["name","john"];
var obj = {};
var newObj = Object.assign(obj, {[arr[0]]: arr[1]});
console.log(newObj);
```